# How can I determine the connection speed for an esata hard drive under Vista 64?

Tags: windows-vista, external-hard-drive, speed, cable, esata

I recently bought a 1.5TB [FreeAgent XTreme](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/external/freeagent/freeagent_xtreme/) external drive to store backups.  I bought both a .5M (almost too short) and 1.5 cable (really too long).  I want to see if I am getting the full 3.0G/sec transfer with either cable.  My Norton 360 backup report was of no help because it didn't give me the total backup time so I could do the computation.

Is there a built in Vista connection speed status like there is for a network connection, or is a a third party tool I can use to measure the connection speed/transfer rate for my esata hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to see if I am getting the full
>   3.0G/sec transfer with either cable.

very easy, 3.0G/sec translates to 393.216 kilobytes or 384 megabytes per second. now copy a file to the eSata drive (e.g. using [FastCopy](http://www.ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en)) and you'll know exactly how far away from the theoretical maximum transfer rate you really are.

3.0 gigabit/sec is the maximum speed the interface can provide for, the disk data transfer rate isn't anywhere near that. as a comparison: i'm transferring data between 2 internal SATA drives at a rate of 65 megabytes per seconds.

however, FastCopy will help you to estimate the difference in speed between the 2 cables

Comment: Goot point about the actual transfer rate. According to PC World, the fastest SATA drive I know about, the WD Velociraptor, had a max burst speed of 250.3 MB/s with average read speed of 105.6 MB/s.

Comment: the 1.5 TB Freeagent sports a Barracuda 7k2 RPM, not really a match for the Velociraptor :)

Comment: Good point on the drive speed being the limiting factor, I feel a bit silly now for forgetting about that.

Comment: sure you can run fancy benchmarks, but all what matters with an external hard drive is how it performs real world tasks, such as copying/moving files. besides, FastCopy as a nice addon to your system anyway, Vista file copy is rather buggy and dreadful slow at times.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, most mechanical based hard drives, much less a normal branded external storage solution, is unable to saturate the full SATA bandwidth, be it SATA-I or SATA-II.

If you really want to be details oriented, don't use Filecopy. Get a proper benchmarking utility for HDD such as HDTach, and get excited (or unexcited) over the graphs and numbers. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Crystal Disk Mark](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html) will benchmark your HD and let you know how fast it is going